# The tag “simple” should be deleted

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

### **NB: the tag no longer exists.**

I found that there is a tag called [simple](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simple) in Ell Stack Exchange. For me, this tag is useless, and I don’t know who created this tag.

Maybe the user want to create the tag for easy questions or even for questions about simple tense. That’s bad.

I think that we should delete this tag, right?

Comment: Related post that has some information about cleaning up tags: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3449/9161

Answer (score 0):

That is not what 'simple' refers to in grammar.

The present simple and past simple are types of verbal construction in English. The 'present simple' contrasts with the present continuous and present perfect. Similarly the 'past simple' contrasts with past continuous or past perfect constructions.

> **Present simple for *BE*:**
> She is a doctor
> She isn't a doctor
> Is she a doctor?
>
> **Present simple for all other verbs:**
> She swims
> She doesn't swim
> Does she swim?

> **Past simple for *BE*:**
> She was a doctor
> She wasn't a doctor
> Was she a doctor?
>
> **Past simple for all other verbs:**
> She swam
> She didn't swim
> Did she swim?

Thus, 'simple' contrasts with 'continuous' and 'perfect'.

However, looks like the tag has already been deleted.

Comment: If a tag exists and has no questions it is either a synonym of some more descriptive tag, or it is on its way to being deleted at the appointed hour.

Comment: @ColleenV Is that because it was misunderstood and has been miscurated?

Comment: It’s just the way the system works. If a tag has no questions, it gets deleted at the end of the day (I don’t remember the exact time) If a tag sticks around more than a day of having zero questions, it’s a synonym for another tag. Some tags get recreated a lot - simple is a typo of a longer tag I think. We could block bad tags that persistently reappear.

Comment: @ColleenV Yep, been deleted.

Comment: I can see why someone might have created the tag (for these tenses) but the name is too confusing so I'm glad it's gone.

Comment: @Laurel Ys, not particularly useful. However, if it had been called "The Simple" instead of "Simple", that would have helped somewhat.

Comment: "Simple tense(s)" would have been the best name, but arguably just using our existing tags is simpler. We have way too many tense tags for even a basic question to fit all that are relevant.

Comment: @Laurel Well, for that part of the EFL community who believe that it's helpful to present the present continuous as a tense, etc. Many of us don't. ;-)

Comment: If [tag:simple] were supposed to be for questions about Simple Present, it should be [tag:simple-present]; for Present Continuous, it should be [tag:present-continuous]. On Stack Exchange, there are not compound tags, so I cannot use [tag:simple]+[tag:present] for Simple Present questions.